# How can I insert placeholders of varied width in a flex layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a CV layout on a website for an artist that has often had multiple exhibitions running simultaneously over the years, and rather than write the same date out several times, I'd like to be able to write it once and have the events listed next to it.

Depending on the number of letters in the dates, the paragraphs are different widths, pushing the grey information text out to the right at varying degrees. I don't mind that the information paragraphs are not perfectly aligned with each other, however can't work out how to leave the date empty on some rows to prevent a duplicate date being written, and still have it aligned with the exhibitions on the same date.

Is there a flex solution for this so I don't have to insert a div of fixed width every time?

https://jsfiddle.net/wcr1y2kp/1/

```css
.cv {
  width: 550px;
}

.cv-heading {
  display: block;
  margin: 82px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
}

.cv-entry {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 20px 0 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.cv-entry p {
  padding: 0px;
}

.cv-date {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  margin-right: 34px;
  color: #000000;
}

.cv-detail {
  color: #79797E;
}
```

```html
<div class="cv">
  <span class="cv-heading">Exhibitions</span>
  <span class="cv-entry">
        <p class="cv-date">February 2021</p>
        <p class="cv-detail">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum</p>
    </span>

  <span class="cv-entry">
        <p class="cv-date">June 2016</p>
        <p class="cv-detail">This exhibition was in June 2016</p>
    </span>

  <span class="cv-entry">
        <p class="cv-date"></p>
        <p class="cv-detail" style="color: red">This exhibition was also in June 2016 but I can't align it with the one above</p>
    </span>

  <span class="cv-entry">
        <p class="cv-date">November 2012</p>
        <p class="cv-detail">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit</p>
    </span>

  <span class="cv-entry">
        <p class="cv-date">May 2011</p>
        <p class="cv-detail">Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: `.cv-date { 0 0 100px }`, although not sure if that is what you are after.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep it without a fixed width if possible. I'd like the each date paragraph to fit the width of the text, and then get the one without a date (to the left of the text in red) to match the width of the one above.

Comment: Like this? -> https://jsfiddle.net/qy54mz72/

Comment: why not just give a width to the date (as wide as your longest date) and then use flex grow on the detail

Comment: Hi Pete, rather than have them all the same width, I was trying to have the detail paragraph the same distance apart from each date paragraph using a margin-right value of say, 30px. The problem is, this doesn't work when there is a date field left blank because I don't think there's a way of getting it to take the width of the one above. To be honest, I might have asked for a solution that isn't really possible here. 

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use flex?
If not the simplest fix will be to use `table`

```css
.cv-heading {
  display: block;
  margin: 82px 0px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000000;
}

.cv {
  width: 550px;
}

.cv td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  padding: 20px 0 16px;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.cv-date {
  margin-right: 34px;
  color: #000000;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.cv-detail {
  color: #79797E;
}
```

```html
<div class="cv-heading">Exhibitions</div>

<table class="cv">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-date">February 2021</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-detail">At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-date">June 2016</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-detail">This exhibition was in June 2016</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-date"></p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-detail" style="color: red">This exhibition was also in June 2016 but I can't align it with the one above</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-date">November 2012</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-detail">Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-date">May 2011</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p class="cv-detail">Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer - the reason I was trying to use flex was so I can set a margin-right value to decide how far the text in the `cv-detail` field sits away from the `cv-date`. If I use tables, they all sit the same distance away based on the longest date field.